# How do I dump a MySQL database using ant?

Tags: java, ant, mysql

I couldn't find any information about how to dump a MySQL database with an ant task.

Do I have to create my own task to do this?

```
ANT script ===generate==> myDataBase.sql
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a target that runs the "mysqldump" command like this:

```
<target name="dump-database">  
    <exec executable="mysqldump" output="database-dump.sql">  
        <arg value="--user=username" />  
        <arg value="--password=password" />  
        <arg value="--host=localhost" />  
        <arg value="--port=3306" />  
        <arg value="mydatabase" />  
    </exec>  
</target>
```

Now you can make the dump by executing **ant dump-database**

Comment: please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835076/ant-build-failed-for-mysql

Answer (score 9):

And **to import** some sql file using ant, that is also useful:

```
    <exec executable="mysql" failonerror="true" input="file.sql">
        <arg value="-u ${user}" />  
        <arg value="-p${pass}" />  
        <arg value="-h ${host}" />  
        <arg value="-P 3306" />  
        <arg value="-D ${database}" />  
    </exec>
```

*note that the correct is **-ppassword**  and not **-p password**

or:

```
    <exec executable="mysql" failonerror="true" input="file.sql">
        <arg value="--user=${user}" />  
        <arg value="--password=${pass}" />  
        <arg value="--host=${host}" />  
        <arg value="--port=3306" />  
        <arg value="--database=${database}" />  
    </exec>
```

It's also nice because it doesn't use external libs/sql drivers like org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Exec task, which will start your script which will perform all actions necessary for dumping (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna make it data driven, try this guy out using the ant sql task:

```
<macrodef name="sql-retrieve-table-schema">
    <attribute name="schema-name"/>
    <attribute name="table-name"/>
    <attribute name="connection-url"/>
    <attribute name="output-file"/>
    <sequential>
        <sql userid="username" url="@{connection-url}"  classpathref="compile.classpath"
            password="apassword" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" print="true" output="@{output-file}"
            showheaders="false" showtrailers="false">
            SHOW CREATE TABLE @{table-name};
        </sql>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410859/19735954, my dump takes 3 hours to complete while it only takes 20 minutes using the mysqldump command directly (backup weighs 20Go).

Direct command :

```
mysqldump --login-path=mysql_serv --skip-comments --max-allowed-packet=128M --extended-insert mysql_database > /road/to/output/file.sql
```

Ant task :

```
<target name="backupBDD">
    <exec executable="mysqldump" output="/road/to/output/file.sql">
        <arg value="--login-path=mysql_serv"/>
        <arg value="--skip-comments" />
        <arg value="--max-allowed-packet=128M" />
        <arg value="--extended-insert" />
        <arg value="mysql_database" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

How to explain this difference ?