# Ant build failed for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, ant, build

When I run Ant build using mysql the following error occur

```
 Cannot run program "mysql" (in directory 
 "D:\Projects\OBSWorkspace\schoolforms\db"):    
  CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

when i run mysql in local cmd the following message occur

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: 
NO)
```

how to run ant for generating and creating database from the script.

Comment: It looks like mysql isn't setup. What are you doing? Are you building a Java project or using Ant as a shell scripting/batch language?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you want to connect to mysql via ant? Please add your code which you are actually use.

Comment: a java project..........but I get sove problem......thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to try to connect with mysql via cmd line, for example int this way `mysql -u root -p root` to know that you are able to do it. Secondly you can do it from ant build using this code:

```
<project name="mysql.test" default="mysqltest">

    <target name="mysqltest">
        <exec executable="cmd.exe">
            <arg value="mysql" />
            <arg value="-u root" />
            <arg value="-p root" />
        </exec>
    </target>

</project>
```

You probably try to do it not via `cmd` and thats why you can't connect.